# cast from pointer to integer of different size and assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c

```
void KnightsFlip( FILE * fin, FILE * fout )
{
    int num;
    fscanf( fin, "%d", &num );
    fprintf( fout, "KnightsFlip:\n" );
    char *string;
    string = ( char ) malloc( ( num + 1 ) * sizeof( char ) );
    if ( string == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Not Memory found" );
    }
    string[num] = '\0';
    KnightsFlipRecursion( string, 0, num, fout );
    fprintf( fout, "\n" );
    free( string );
}
```

I am trying to allocate memory but I am getting two warnings cast from pointer to integer of different size and assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change 'string = ( char ) malloc( ( num + 1 ) * sizeof( char ) );' to 'string = ( char *) malloc( ( num + 1 ) * sizeof( char ) );'

Comment: It fixed the warnings but now it does not want to allocate memory it is printing Not memory found.

Comment: are you giving very big number as input 'num'. It appears system is not able to allocate that much memory.

Comment: You forgot to copy and paste the exact warning messages to your question, including the line numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of issues in your code.

First you're casting the result from `malloc()` to a `char` and not a `char*`.  This is what is causing the error your question refers to.

Secondly - what happens when `malloc()` fails, returning NULL.  The code prints a message sure, but it continues on anyway, as if everything was ok.

A better approach might be:

```
void KnightsFlip( FILE * fin, FILE * fout )
{
    int num;
    fscanf( fin, "%d", &num );
    fprintf( fout, "KnightsFlip:\n" );
    char *string;
    string = ( char* ) malloc( ( num + 1 ) * sizeof( char ) );
    if ( string == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Not Memory found" );
    }
    else
    {
        string[num] = '\0';
        KnightsFlipRecursion( string, 0, num, fout );
        fprintf( fout, "\n" );
        free( string );
    }
}
```

Comment: Note the cast `( char* ) ` is not needed and `sizeof( char )  == 1` so could use `string = malloc(num + 1);`

Comment: @chux - At code reviews I participated in, `malloc()` has *always* been called in the form `malloc( number_of_elements * sizeof( element) )`.  I guess the theory is that if the type of element changes, it's a nudge towards better correctness.  So I personally keep to this format for all calls to `malloc()`, `char` or not.

Comment: Consider `malloc(number_of_elements * sizeof *pointer)`.  No need for a type anywhere, easier to code right, review and maintain than `malloc( number_of_elements * sizeof( element) )`

Comment: Yeah that's a good way to do it. It does make the statement somewhat less "self-documenting" though, since you need to cross-reference `*pointer` to see what type is actually being allocated.